# How to add query hint inside a view

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a view that contains multiple joins, and this makes the query run really slow. It takes more than 3 hours to execute this query via the `VIEW`.

I the copied the `SELECT ...` part of the statement from the view into a different query window and added the following query hint:

```
...OPTION (USE HINT ( 'FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' ), maxdop 0)`
```

Executing the stand-alone `SELECT` statement with the query hint reduces the execution time down to 3 minutes.

After that, I tried to adapt this query hint in the original view, and I got this error in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio):

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

So, how can I add this query hint to the view so that the resulting query from the view becomes fast?

Comment: Please **always** tag your questions with your RDBMS (Microsoft SQL Server?) and version as these can be very important in giving a correct answer. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: As a side, is the MAXDOP 0 helping? or is just the force legacy estimation?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you will apply this table hint when you are referencing the view. [KenJ from SQLServerCentral](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/users/202/kenj.html) posted this answer which applies to your question:

```
select * from your_view
option(use hint('force_legacy_cardinality_estimation'))
```

[SQLServerCentral Thread](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/149715/force-legacy-cardinality-estimation-hint-in-view.html)

You can find another definition from [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017).

> [force_legacy_cardinality_estimation]...Applies the specified table
>   hint to the table or view that corresponds to exposed_object_name. We
>   recommend using a table hint as a query hint only in the context of a
>   plan guide.